# Laravel - Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost

Tags: laravel

I am learning laravel, and working on a blog application. Anyway, I made my model for articles + migration, and migrated it fine. But now that I want to pull articles from database in my controller, I get "Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost".

And yes, I've changed my settings in .env file, and restarted the server. Still wont work. I tried everything from that other thread on this same issue, but nothing worked.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Here are the mysql settings in .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=faks_blog
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

If migration worked, then settings must be correct. Otherwise, how would laravel make all those tables?
I also use HeidiSql to access my database, and those login credentials worked.

Comment: Show which settings exactly you configured and how, and explain how you verified that you actually entered the correct credentials.

Comment: I added my answer above.

Comment: It's not using that .env file, because the file specifies `DB_USERNAME=root` and the error shows it tries to log in as a user named `homestead`.

Comment: Have you try to replace localhost by 127.0.0.1 for DB_HOST setting ?

Comment: I tried replacing localhost with 127.0.0.1, and didnt work. Also, why isnt it using the .env file? :(

Comment: change both your config/database.php and .env if that didn't help remove the env file and try again

Comment: this is more than likely because your server hasn't been restarted. The .env file is cached. If you are in the local environment all you have to do is re-run `php artisan serve`

Comment: As already said, i restarted server multiple times. Also, I tried changing both config/database.php and .env, and didnt work. I also deleted .env file, still same error... Im so lost here :(

Answer (score 0):

Just remove empty brackets after DB_PASSWORD

write like this 
DB_PASSWORD=

Please tell if it helps

Answer (score 0):

When you make changes to the `.env` file you should always run `php artisan config:cache` because Laravel caches config to avoid reading the same files twice.